# Snowflake query to convert date-time-stamp to date format

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a column name 'date_val' that contains value in the form of **02-09-2022 09:52:26** (MM_DD_YYY_HH_MM_SS format) using **SNOWFLAKE ONLY**. But I want to convert into just MM_DD_YYY format.
I have tried 2 approaches:

Input: 02-09-2022 09:52:26

Desired O/P:  02-09-2022

1)TRY_TO_DATE("date_val")

O/P: It gives me output as **NULL**

2)TO_DATE("date_val")

O/P:Error: Date '07-31-2023 08:41:01' is not recognized.

Comment: `to_date(date_val, 'MM-DD-YYYY')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 select to_date (date_val, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH:MI:SS');
```

EDIT:
In Snowflake the date displayed in ISO format by default 'YYYY-MM-DD'

You can change how it will be displayed for your users for example on session level:

```
alter session set DATE_OUTPUT_FORMAT = 'MM-DD-YYYY';
```

[Doc](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters#date-output-format)

Comment: Works like magic. Thanks!